# MSSQL: GROUP BY and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that contain info about users. I would like to find how many of each type of item in each bucket a person has.

I'm not grasping why this wouldn't work. Does table join order matter or something I not aware of?

A sample of the tables:

PERSONS

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |

BUCKETS

| ID | LABEL | PERSONID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Random | 1 |
| 2 | Vacation | 1 |

THINGS

| ID | BUCKETID | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Image | abc12 |
| 2 | 1 | Image | abc13 |
| 3 | 1 | Video | abc34 |
| 4 | 1 | Image | def12 |
| 5 | 1 | Video | def34 |

```sql
SELECT P.NAME, B.LABEL, T.TYPE, COUNT(T.TYPE)
FROM PERSONS P
  LEFT JOIN BUCKETS B ON
    B.PERSONID = P.ID
  LEFT JOIN THING T ON
    T.BUCKETID = B.ID
GROUP BY P.NAME, B.LABEL, T.TYPE
```

I expect it to return:

```
John, Random, Images, 3
John, Random, Videos, 2
```

But it returns:

```
John, Random, Images, 5
John, Random, Videos, 5
```

I have tried `COUNT(*)` which results in the same and `COUNT(DISTINCT T.TYPE)` which of course returns 1 as the count.

This works perfectly in MySQL. Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcb3wiPMSAFBXrWbgYxuMH/8

MSSQL is a different beast all together.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added sample tables.

Comment: What does your expected counts of 3 & 2 actually represent? ie, what are you trying to "count"?

Comment: GROUP BY in a subquery before you JOIN.

Comment: I have 3 tables that contain info about users. I would like to find how many of each type of item in each bucket a person has.

Comment: Your query works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adfc39aedaa093f8227fefae248a5e00

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `count(distinct)` of some sort.  I would speculate:

```
SELECT P.NAME, B.LABEL, T.TYPE, COUNT(DISTINCT T.BUCKETID)
FROM PERSONS P LEFT JOIN
     BUCKETS B
     ON B.PERSONID = P.ID LEFT JOIN
     THING T
     ON T.BUCKETID = B.ID
GROUP BY P.NAME, B.LABEL, T.TYPE;
```

Comment: I've tried that. It returns 1 for every row.